# Reading integers from a file in C using a while-loop and getw(f) != EOF

Tags: c, file, while-loop, integer, eof

I pretty new to C, or well, very new to C. I'm trying to write integers to a file using putw(), and then I try to read them using getw(), I read them using a while loop until EOF. But the loop dies prematurely, and it seems to do so when getw() gets the integer 26 from the file. I'm at a complete loss.

Basically I want to printf the integers that I previously saved to the file, using putw(), every 7th iteration I print a new line. It works all the way until getw() encounters the integer 26, that kills the loop, even if it isnt EOF. No matter how many integers I have in the file, it works only until getw() encounters 26.  I´ve tried using fscanf but didnt get that to work either. Please help a beginner.

```
void readfile() {
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("INTEGERS.DAT", "r");
    int num, xar=1;
    if (f==NULL){
        printf("NO file detected.\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        while((num = getw(f)) != EOF) {
            printf("%d ", num);
            if ( xar % 7 == 0) {
                printf("\n");
            }
            xar++;
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not any other reason than that I'm very, very new to this. I shall try at once.

Comment: @KamilCuk Hmmm. That [spec](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getw.3.html) mentions `EOF` and no `wint_t`. Which `getw` function do you mean? Also, reading and writing integers won't work too well with `putc`/`getc` or did I miss something?

Comment: Premature EOF on a value of 26 means you're (a) on Windows and (b) in text mode, where 26 is control-Z.  You need to open the file in binary mode.  `f = fopen("INTEGERS.DAT", "rb");`.  Also use `"wb`" in the program where you write the file.

Comment: @Gerhardh This appears to be the old (very old!) [`getw`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getw), not anything to do with wide characters or Unicode.

Comment: @SteveSummit, after a quick edit in the code using your solution, my program now work as intended. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @noRobotNoPro You will probably also have a problem if you have the number -1 in your data, because that will also be wrongly interpreted as EOF, although for a different reason.  If you have that problem, you can fix it by changing `while((num = getw(f)) != EOF)` to `while((num = getw(f)) != EOF && !feof(f))`.  (Normally you never need to use `feof()`, but with `getw` is one case where you do — which is one reason that `getw` is considered kinda obsolete and disrecommended.)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate the format of your data file, but noting that you are opening the file with an "r" parameter, that would indicate that the data in the file is in a text format and not a binary format.  So using that information and a bit of artistic license, I created a code snippet to build some text data with an integer value per line/record in a file, and then read the data in that file utilizing a tweaked version of your readfile function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void save_int(void)
{
    int entry = 999;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("INTEGERS.DAT", "w");

    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            printf("Enter an integer or enter '0' to quit data entry: ");
            scanf("%d", &entry);

            if (entry == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            fprintf(fp, "%d\n", entry);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return;
}

void readfile()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("INTEGERS.DAT", "r");
    char number[16];
    int value;
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("NO file detected.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
            value = fscanf(fp, "%s", number);
            if (value < 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            printf("%d ", atoi(number));
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
    save_int();
    readfile();
    return 0;
}
```

Some items to point out.

- Each integer value is being written with a newline character to the text file, so that would be a caveat if your file actually is in a different format such as storing integers on the same line with some type of delimiter between the integer values.
- In reading in the integer data from the created text file, fscanf is used for this task - you might get suggestions and other answers utilizing other functions such as fgets.  There are pros and cons, so often it comes down to what is most familiar and comfortable to you.
- Since the values were stored as string values, they are read in to a string and then converted to an integer utilizing the standard atoi function.  Again, this is just a simple way to do this that I am familiar with.  By all means, view any alternative answers you might get and/or comments added later to this answer.

With that, following is some sample output at the terminal.

```
@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Integers/bin/Release$ ./Integers 
Enter an integer or enter '0' to quit data entry: 14
Enter an integer or enter '0' to quit data entry: 566
Enter an integer or enter '0' to quit data entry: 65335
Enter an integer or enter '0' to quit data entry: 122
Enter an integer or enter '0' to quit data entry: 18
Enter an integer or enter '0' to quit data entry: 0
14 566 65335 122 18 

@Dev:~/C_Programs/Console/Integers/bin/Release$ cat INTEGERS.DAT 
14
566
65335
122
18
```

Go ahead and test this out to see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Comment: Note: infinite loop should `scanf("%d", &entry);` return non-1.

Comment: `fscanf(fp, "%s", number);` better as `fscanf(fp, "%15s", number);`.